# Getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG Error

Tags: java, testing, automation, automated-tests

I'm trying to execute my testng.xml file from main method using the code below. But getting a NoClassDefFoundError. Any idea what may have caused this issue?

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    suites.add("testng.xml");
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG
        at com.automation.app.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: missing the import line ?

Comment: @vincrichaud: I'm using "import org.testng.TestNG;"

Comment: How do you run class? Using Eclipse?

Comment: @user7294900: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. This happens when I run java -jar target/automation-1.jar command.

Comment: It is a real problem. I have it too. In 2014 the problem didn't exist. In 2015 we had to set "for whole project" in configuration. And since 2019 even that won't help. Every next version of IntelliJ works worse and worse with tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using "maven-assembly-plugin" and "maven-dependency-plugin",  Then creating the manifest.mf file in resources/meta-inf folder and adding the following information.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: {PROVIDE THE MAIN CLASS HERE}
```

Comment: Why suddenly, TestNG had got a need for main or manifest? What is the sense of your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are missing the dependent libraries on your class path when you are executing the jar because the jar only has the classes from you project.

What you need here is either

> 1. build an executable jar with all the dependencies

or

> 2. specify the dependencies on command line

e.g. 
    `java -cp your.jar:lib/*`

where `libs/*` is a path to your dependency JARs

I would recommend option one as you can run that jar any where if it has all the dependencies included in jar.

Comment: Is there a recommended way I can create build and executable jar? I tried option 2 and it still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Its related to the Testng Library.
Add library:
Right click project -> Build path -> Configure build path ->Java Build Path -> Library -> Add library-> select TestNG -> Apply and close.

It worked for me.